# NetSuite - Postman - REST - "Incorrect data center requested!"

Tags: soap, postman, netsuite

I'm using Postman to connect to NetSuite and all the setup and authorization were made.
When I'm trying to use GET method for a Example template, the request return the Status 200 OK, but with this error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>
                soapenv:Server.userException
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring>
                Incorrect data center requested! The data center you are requesting is not the data center where your account is hosted. To obtain the correct URL for your request, please use the SOAP getDataCenterUrls operation.
            </faultstring>
            <detail>
                <platformFaults:unexpectedErrorFault xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_/services/rest/record/v1/metadata-catalog/customer.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformFaults:code>
                        USER_ERROR
                    </platformFaults:code>
                    <platformFaults:message>
                        Incorrect data center requested! The data center you are requesting is not the data center where your account is hosted. To obtain the correct URL for your request, please use the SOAP getDataCenterUrls operation.
                    </platformFaults:message>
                </platformFaults:unexpectedErrorFault>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">
                    acct027.prod.svale.netledger.com
                </ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My URL setup is the same from my Company URL setup:
[image: Company URL]

[image: PostMan Setup]

I've seen other cases like that, and all the responses were related to get the address in the company URL as I've done it.

What can be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Odd, they no longer want data center based URLs to be used. It as all account based. So for restlets it would be  https://#######.restlets.api.netsuite.com where ##### is your NetSuite account number. Look in NetSuite under Setup -> Company -> Company Information, Company URLs tab.

Comment: Hi Brian! thanks for your reply! I'm using this address. That's what is really weird. I don't why my images isn't showing, but it is in my original post.

Comment: eklon, did you ever figure out this issue?  I'm getting the same thing when making REST calls.  It works fine when my Netsuite environment is pointing at dev, but not when pointing at our sandbox env.  I'm using the user account number for the right environment and it still shows that I'm using the wrong data center.

Comment: @Kirby, I just posted my answear.  I do expect that it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I had some errors in my postman setup:

The Account_ID, should be entered exactly like this, in capital letters:
[image]

But the company URL, and Rest Services should stay like that:
[image]

And it worked for me.